# Changing colour palette for multiple choice questions in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, survey

After searching around this forum, I have figured out the code to plot multiple response survey questions like these:

```
         b1_1     b1_2     b1_3    b1_4
           1        1        0        1
           0        1        0        0
           1        0        1        1
           0        0        0        1
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
data%>% 
  gather(question, response, starts_with("b1_")) %>%
  filter(response != "") %>%
  group_by(question) %>%
  summarise(score = sum(response)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=question, y=score)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("b1_1" = "Individual (lease/certificate)", "b1_2" = "Individual (law)","b1_3" = "Communal","b1_4" = "State owned")) +
  labs ( x= "Investment", y="Count") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 11),
        axis.title=element_text(size=15,face="bold")) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues")
```

Everything seems to be working fine except scale_fill_brewer(); the bars are still appearing in grey. Is this because I'm using reformatted data from multiple questions? I can't seem to figure out what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell `ggplot` which column to use as a `fill` by adding it to the `aes()` call. Assuming you want to color by question, that means adding `aes(fill = question)` to `geom_bar()`:

```r
data%>% 
  gather(question, response, starts_with("b1_")) %>%
  filter(response != "") %>%
  group_by(question) %>%
  summarise(score = sum(response))  %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=question, y=score)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = question)) + # this line changed
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("b1_1" = "Individual (lease/certificate)", "b1_2" = "Individual (law)","b1_3" = "Communal","b1_4" = "State owned")) +
  labs ( x= "Investment", y="Count") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 11),
        axis.title=element_text(size=15,face="bold")) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues")
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this previously and got this error: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'question' not found

Comment: Do you get that error now if you copy and paste this code?

Comment: Yes, I get the same error

Comment: Sorry - assigning color, shape or fill to aesthetics by using column names in the `aes()` call is essentially how `ggplot` works. That should work and it does for me - I'm not really sure how else I can help you.

Comment: I'll look around more. Cheers!